# WKWebView: resource load delegate dropped?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

Previously in the OSX `WebView`, we had the `WebResourceLoadDelegate` callbacks to get informed about the events related to the resources embedded in the page we are loading. I used these calls to filter and redirect the HTTP requests coming from the page itself. Now, this functionality seems to be completely missing in `WKWebView` (OSX 10.10 beta 3), and I didn't find traces of it in the public WebKit source either.

Does anybody know how am I supposed to work this around?

ps. for the record, I've already submitted a feature request at rdar://17695683 .